# How to change an dataset schema without deleting dataset and having to remove filters on Personalize?

Tags: amazon-personalize

I noticed that one of my schema fields that I need to filter on is a booleaN and as you can't filter on a boolean I need to change the schema.

I was able to create a new schema using the new Python SDK but can't see how I can update the schema?

You can delete the dataset, but then that would mean having to delete all the filters, which would mean our service has to go down? (Everything in the API uses a filter).

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

As of [July 2023](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/07/amazon-personalize-add-columns-existing-datasets/), you can update the schema on an existing dataset (see [UpdateDataset](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/API_UpdateDataset.html) API). This allows you to add a new column to a dataset without having to delete the dataset (and related resources like filters). Columns cannot be changed or deleted (yet), though. See [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/updating-dataset-schema.html) for more details.

Prior answer below retained below since it still applies when columns need to be changed or removed.

---

Unfortunately you cannot change a schema for an existing dataset since (as you found) it impacts existing immutable resources like filters. A workaround is to create a new dataset group to hold your new dataset. This means you'll need to import your data (conforming to the new schema) in the new dataset, train models, create new filters, and a new campaign. Once the campaign is ready in the new dataset group, you can switch your app to use the new campaign and tear down the old dataset group. This sort of blue/green dataset group approach is somewhat common with Personalize for reasons such as this.